# TextViews are not taking up set layout_weight in view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, textview

My XML is the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/llBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="2" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llPhone"
        android:layout_weight=".9"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivMyPhone"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/about_logo_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/about_logo_size"
            android:src="@drawable/andicon" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llPhoneInfo"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:weightSum="6"
        android:gravity="center" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llBrand"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llPhone"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBrand"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone Brand: "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvBrandName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llModel"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llBrand"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvModel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Phone Model: "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvModelName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llVersion"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llModel"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersion"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android Version: "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvVersionNumber"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llCode"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llVersion"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCode"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Android Codename: "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvCodeName"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llAPI"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llCode"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAPI"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="API Level: "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvAPILevel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/llScreen"
        android:layout_below="@+id/llAPI"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScreen"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Screen Size (WxH): "
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvScreenSize"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

It displays the following:

[image]

I am looking to make the logo take up 1/4 of the screen from top and the rest of the information should be 3/4 of the screen. But for some reason they are all clustered together. How do I resolve it?

I want to do the following (rough sketch):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am looking to make the logo take up 1/4 of the screen from top and
>   the rest of the information should be 3/4 of the screen

You need to do the following. Remove the attribute `android:weightSum` from `llBottom`, set `android:layout_weight` to 1 in `llPhone`, set `android:layout_weight` to 3 in `llPhoneInfo`.

The total sume of the weights will be 4, `llPhone` will take up 1/4 of the screen and `llPhoneInfo` will take up 3/4 of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/llBottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPhone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView ... />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llPhoneInfo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="6" >

        ...    

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Do a similar calculation for the other layouts.

You should also consider using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead of several nested `LinearLayouts` for better performance.

Comment: RelativeLayout does not offer layout_weight :/

Comment: Adding a background to the root LinearLayout causes the entire `layout_weight` to not work.

Comment: The RelativeLayout can be used within the second LinearLayout (llPhoneInfo).

Comment: I know it's weird but changing the background, I was able to use my own layout and it worked just fine. Thanks though

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of code duplication here. It seems to me that you should only have one Linear Layout with an ImageView and a listView inside. Use layout weight for both child views inside the Linear Layout and programmatically. There are a lot of good tutorials out there for setting up custom list views. This one covers everything you need. [AndroidListView](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)